# How to install Notes Designer and Domino Server in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, ibm

I've managed to install `Notes Client 9.0.1` but since I'm a developer I need the `Notes Designer` and the `Domino Server` also installed.

How do I install Notes Designer and Domino Server 9.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LotusNotes) out

Answer (score 1):

There is no Notes Designer for Linux.
Look for alternatives like virtualized Windows guest or Wine to run the Windows version of Notes Designer.